# Dual AWS load balancing appliances with VIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have been tasked with configuring two AWS load balancers and configuring a VIP. I see plenty of answers for using dual Linux machines to do load balancing but not two AWS load balancing appliances.

Comment: You are now tasked with explaining why this requirement is silly.

Comment: You could use Route53 to balance between two ELBs. Based on what you've told us it would be completely redundant, but it's probably possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ELBs then they are already engineered to be HA.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Load Balancers are not one device, they are a highly available service that runs over three availability zones (AZ = data centers).

The CNAME for the ELB resolves to a number of IP addresses, and that can change over time. If your load goes up high enough you could have dozens of IPs / servers doing load balancing for your application. If load is low you will still have three IPs / servers doing load balancing.

The [AWS ELB details page](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/) gives you more information. The documentation likely goes deeper. You could watch an [ELB Deep Dive from ReInvent on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy7zNaDTYGQ).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is very informative.